# PLSQL - is there a generic data type?

Tags: oracle, plsql, types, type-conversion

I would like to archive some situation-based type conversions in PLSQL. I guess, it is just not possible but, let's see: Can I do something like the below:

```
function my_type( p_type in variant) return varchar2
as
begin
    
    if is_date(p_type) and p_type = trunc(p_type ,'dd') 
    then 
        return to_string(p_type,'some_setting'); 
    end if;
    -- and so on for numbers and other date-type cases
    
end;
```

I am also happy about other ideas. Oracle would convert the data into varchar2 anyways. I am just not happy about how it does it. Are there maybe some flexible data settings that you can recommend?

Best, Peter

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not happy about how it does it"? You can control the default conversion in detail with NLS-Parameter settings on session and database level or if required on individual statement. ANYDATA consumes more space and you cannot index them.

Comment: Hi Wernfried, basically, I don't want to touch Database defaults and I am writing a tool that others would use too. So basically, I cannot change NLS before it is too late.

Comment: I guess I was simply searching for the "anydata" type.

Comment: You don't have to modify the database defaults. You can set it on session level. And you can define your personal defaults by setting NLS parameters as environment variables or (in case of Windows) in Registry. I.e. they are defined even before you start any Oracle related application.

Comment: Thank you Wernfried, this information is valuable by itself. However, if I have a string-in string-out function. that is supposed to handle another person's number/date input, then I believe that his session settings will apply for the date to varchar2 conversion and I will be too late with my settings even if I start an autonomous session with my function.

Comment: BTW, personally I get really pissed off, if a software forces any hard coded output formats and ignores personal preferences. Usually, this is a sing for badly programmed software. And in general, software shall work independently from any user preference settings.

Comment: Yes, software products such as HTML pages should work independently from user settings. That is what I am trying to archive with my function. Please let's not overextend the comments here. You can PM-me if you like to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to pass different data types to a function then it is not possible to have many different versions of a function with different data types; however, you can pass the `ANYDATA` data type:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION ANYDATA_TO_STRING(
  p_anydata IN ANYDATA
) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  v_typeid      PLS_INTEGER;
  v_anytype     ANYTYPE;
  v_result_code PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  v_typeid := p_anydata.GetType( typ => v_anytype );
  CASE v_typeid
  WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_NUMBER THEN
    DECLARE
      v_value NUMBER;
    BEGIN
      v_result_code := p_anydata.GetNumber( v_value );
      RETURN TO_CHAR( v_value );
    END;
  WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_VARCHAR2 THEN
    DECLARE
      v_value VARCHAR2(4000);
    BEGIN
      v_result_code := p_anydata.GetVarchar2( v_value );
      RETURN v_value;
    END;
  WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_DATE THEN
    DECLARE
      v_value DATE;
    BEGIN
      v_result_code := p_anydata.GetDate( v_value );
      RETURN TO_CHAR( v_value, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' );
    END;
  END CASE;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
/
```

Then:

```
WITH table_name (value) AS (
  SELECT ANYDATA.ConvertDate(SYSDATE)     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT ANYDATA.ConvertNumber(42)        FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT ANYDATA.ConvertVarchar2('Hello') FROM DUAL
)
SELECT ANYDATA_TO_STRING(value)
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

| ANYDATA_TO_STRING(VALUE) |
| --- |
| 2023-01-16 14:48:37 |
| 42 |
| Hello |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GXGeC8pg)

Answer (score 2):

ANYDATA

Example:

```
create table t_anydata (
  nsq number(19,0) primary key,
  anyd anydata
);

insert into t_anydata(nsq, anyd) values (1, sys.anyData.convertNumber(5) ) ;
insert into t_anydata(nsq, anyd) values (2, sys.anyData.convertDate(to_date('01-10-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy')) ) ;
insert into t_anydata(nsq, anyd) values (3, sys.anyData.convertVarchar2('test varchar') ) ;
insert into t_anydata(nsq, anyd) values (4, sys.anyData.convertChar('c') ) ;
insert into t_anydata(nsq, anyd) values (5, sys.anyData.convertBDouble(3.14159) ) ;
insert into t_anydata(nsq, anyd) values (6, sys.anyData.ConvertTimestamp(TIMESTAMP '1997-01-31 09:26:50.12') ) ;
insert into t_anydata(nsq, anyd) values (7, sys.anyData.ConvertTimestampTZ(TIMESTAMP '1997-01-31 09:26:50.12') ) ;
insert into t_anydata(nsq, anyd) values (8, sys.anyData.ConvertTimestampLTZ(TIMESTAMP '1997-01-31 09:26:50.12') ) ;
insert into t_anydata(nsq, anyd) values (9, sys.anyData.ConvertCollection( sys.odcivarchar2list( 'abcd', 'efgh' ) ) ) ;
insert into t_anydata(nsq, anyd) values (10, sys.anyData.ConvertCollection( sys.odcinumberlist( 1.1, 2.2, 3.3 ) ) ) ;

commit ;

SELECT nsq, 
    CASE sys.anyData.gettypename(anyd) 
        WHEN 'SYS.NUMBER' THEN
            TO_CHAR(SYS.ANYDATA.accessNumber(anyd))
        WHEN 'SYS.VARCHAR2' THEN
            SYS.ANYDATA.accessVarchar2(anyd)
        WHEN 'SYS.CHAR' THEN
            SYS.ANYDATA.accessChar(anyd)
        WHEN 'SYS.DATE' THEN
            TO_CHAR(SYS.ANYDATA.accessDate(anyd), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
        WHEN 'SYS.TIMESTAMP' THEN
            TO_CHAR(SYS.ANYDATA.accessTimestamp(anyd), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
        WHEN 'SYS.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE' THEN
            TO_CHAR(SYS.ANYDATA.accessTimestampTZ(anyd), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
        WHEN 'SYS.TIMESTAMP_WITH_LTZ' THEN
            TO_CHAR(SYS.ANYDATA.accessTimestampLTZ(anyd), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
        WHEN 'SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST' THEN
            'COLLECTION'
    END as value, 
    sys.anyData.gettypename(anyd), vsize(anyd) 
FROM t_anydata 
;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches:

1. Use `if ... then ... else ...` statements and perform processing in the branches. It makes the code less readable and maintainable, but it doesn't require extra objects. Then you may use a unified container of the data (for example, `anydata`).
2. Use overloading and divide responsibility: perform datatype-dependent processing and serialization in each individual instance of the datatype and then bring the results together. It's possible in Oracle as long as it allows function overloading in packages.

**Note** that it may cause unexpected results for `varchar2` parameter, because it may cause implicit conversion for supported datatypes for which there's no overloaded function exist.

> ```
> create package pkg_my_to_varchar
> as
>   function f_prepare(p_number in number) return varchar2;
>   function f_prepare(p_date in date) return varchar2;
>   function f_prepare(p_timestamp_tz in timestamp with time zone) return varchar2;
>   function f_prepare(p_varchar in varchar2) return varchar2;
>
>   function f_all_together(
>     p1 varchar2,
>     p2 varchar2 default null,
>     p3 varchar2 default null,
>     p4 varchar2 default null,
>     p5 varchar2 default null,
>     p6 varchar2 default null,
>     p7 varchar2 default null,
>     p8 varchar2 default null,
>     p9 varchar2 default null
>   ) return varchar2;
>
> end pkg_my_to_varchar;/
> ```

> ```
> create package body pkg_my_to_varchar
> as
>   function f_prepare(
>     p_number in number
>   ) return varchar2
>   as
>   begin
>     return 'I''ve processed the number: ' || to_char(p_number, 'RN');
>   end;
>
>   function f_prepare(
>     p_date in date
>   ) return varchar2
>   as
>   begin
>     return 'I''ve processed the date: ' || to_char(p_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS "and some stuff"');
>   end;
>
>   function f_prepare(
>     p_timestamp_tz in timestamp with time zone
>   ) return varchar2
>   as
>   begin
>     return 'I''ve processed the timestamp with TZ: ' || to_char(p_timestamp_tz, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM');
>   end;
>
>   function f_prepare(
>     p_varchar in varchar2
>   ) return varchar2
>   as
>   begin
>     return 'I''ve processed the string: ' || p_varchar;
>   end;
>
>
>   function f_all_together(
>     p1 varchar2,
>     p2 varchar2 default null,
>     p3 varchar2 default null,
>     p4 varchar2 default null,
>     p5 varchar2 default null,
>     p6 varchar2 default null,
>     p7 varchar2 default null,
>     p8 varchar2 default null,
>     p9 varchar2 default null
>   ) return varchar2
>   as
>   begin
>     return p1 || chr(10) || p2 || chr(10) || p3 || chr(10) || p4 || chr(10) || p5 || chr(10) || p6 || chr(10) || p7 || chr(10) || p8 || chr(10) || p9;
>   end;
> end pkg_my_to_varchar;/
> ```

> ```
> with a(n, d, ts, vc) as (
>   select
>     123.456,
>     sysdate,
>     systimestamp at time zone '+07:30',
>     'qwerty'
>   from dual
> )
> select
>   a.*
>   , pkg_my_to_varchar.f_all_together(
>       pkg_my_to_varchar.f_prepare(n),
>       pkg_my_to_varchar.f_prepare(d),
>       pkg_my_to_varchar.f_prepare(ts),
>       pkg_my_to_varchar.f_prepare(vc)
>   ) as concat_all
> from a
> ```

| N | D | TS | VC | CONCAT_ALL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123.456 | 16-JAN-23 | 16-JAN-23 23.13.00.685956 +07:30 | qwerty | I've processed the number: CXXIII I've processed the date: 2023-01-16 15:43:00 and some stuff I've processed the timestamp with TZ: 2023-01-16 23:13:00.685956000 +07:30 I've processed the string: qwerty |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/k47D0y5p)